# Related to JMeter response time and reports

Tags: performance, jmeter

While running JMeter for some pages in the application:

1. The response time for a page is differing every time and the variation is more How can we tell the final response time for that page?
2. For some pages like Create,update getting 100% error percentage after adding Http Header Manager, Http Cookie Manager also please give me solution to avoid that error percentage.
3. By using JMeter Summary report,how can we tell the developers where to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

Following are my answers:

1. The response time for a page is differing every time and the variation is more How can we tell the final response time for that page?

**Answer:**

It depends on a lot of factors. Is the load constant/varies? Depends on server and client (JMeter) machines configuration and system resources availability etc. Little variations in the response times is as expected. We use `99th percentile, 95th percentile,` [90th percentile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html), `Average, min, max` fields (available in [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)) to evaluate the overall performance. So, If [90th percentile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) of response time is 3 seconds, it tells that out of 100, 90 times the response time is 3 seconds, and remaining 10 times more than 3 seconds.

2. For some pages like Create, update getting 100% error percentage after adding Http Header Manager, Http Cookie Manager also please give me solution to avoid that error percentage.

**Answer:**

Adding HTTP Cookie Manager, HTTP Header Manager don't give errors. Either you are sending wrong HTTP request or Server is overloaded, to rejecting all the HTTP requests (ConnectException, SocketException). so, please look from these perspectives. JMeter marks an HTTP Sampler as an error when it receives 4** or 5** status codes or Non-HTTP response codes (SocketException etc).

3. By using JMeter Summary report, how can we tell the developers where to change the code

**Answer:**

You can only get to know which requests performed well and which are not w.r.t. response times and error rates. You can't pin point the issues using Summary reports. For that, you really need to analyze server logs.